# c++ undefined reference to vtable exception

Tags: c++, g++

I've searched many answers but none of them can solve my problem, I'm new to c++, this issue is quite wired to me. Below is a simplified extraction of my code.

TestHeader.h:

```
#ifndef NAMESPACE_TESTHEADER_H_
#define NAMESPACE_TESTHEADER__H_

namespace Namespace {

class TestHeader {

    public:

    TestHeader(const std::string& str) : anyString_(str) { }

    virtual std::string methodOne(const std::string& param) const;

    virtual ~TestHeader() { anyString_.clear(); }

    protected:
        std::string anyString_;
};
}

#endif //NAMESPACE_TESTHEADER__H_
```

TestHeader.cpp:

```
#include "TestHeader.h"

using namespace std;

namespace Namespace {

TestHeader::TestHeader(const std::string& str):anyString_(str) { <do something>; }

std::string TestHeader::methodOne(const std::string& param) const
{
    return <A string>;
}

TestHeader::~TestHeader() {
   anyString_.clear();
}
}
```

What I did was simply call this line in any other .cpp in my package:

```
#include "TestHeader.h"
TestHeader testHeader("whatever");
```

The build failed by throwing

```
error: undefined reference to 'vtable for Namespace::TestHeader'
the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
```

**The most weird thing is: if I comment out `virtual std::string methodOne(const std::string& str) const;` in header and its implementation in .cpp, OR, if I comment out `: anyString_(str)` after constructor and `anyString_.clear();` in destructor together in header only, the build will succeed.**

Comment: Why have you defined the constructor and destructor twice?  It shouldn't be compiling, which makes me think that you have not compiled and linked your sources properly

Comment: I think it will not compile redefination of constructor and destructor.

Comment: You don't include `std::string` in your header. There's no way the failure is only on linkage. Post a proper [mcve], not a dumbed down version of it that doesn't reproduce anything.

Comment: There is no need for `anyString_.clear();` in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly You should not define the constructor and destructor twice. It shouldn't be compiling as mentioned by Curious in comments

Second I assume that you want don't the class to be abstract as there is no Runtime polymorphism implemented which is the basic use of Virtual functions.

If you don't want the class `TestHeader` to be abstract remove the `virtual` keyword which is referring to `Virtual Table`.C++ compiler inserts Virtual Table for every class having virtual function or class inherited from the class that has virtual functions.

Better study the use of `Virtual` keyword and then write the code.
Here are quick links for the same
[Link 1](https://www.go4expert.com/articles/virtual-table-vptr-t16544/)
[Link 2](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/virtual-function-and-virtual-table-in-c/)

Also, I think you need to revisit few concepts from Destructor `virtual ~TestHeader() { anyString_.clear(); }` does not make any sense. In fact, there is no base class which in turn denies the use of `Virtual Destructor` which is used in case of `Inheritance`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, include `#include <string>` at the top of your header file.  I am guessing the error is because you have not linked the object file produced after compiling `TestHeader.cpp` with the source file that contains the declaration and initialization for the variable named `testHeader`

Compile these with the following command and you should see a linker error that complains saying that you have multiple definitions for the constructor

```
g++ -std=c++14 TestHeader.cpp yourfile.cpp
```

After you see those errors, remove the multiple definitions, either put all your definitions in the cpp file or only put them in one place and then recompile and link with the above command.  The linker error should be gone.